# How to create a select query that ignores rows that have a certain reference to a 3rd table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, let's say they are `fruit`, `fruit_data` and `data`. A row in the `fruit` table may have **0-n** `data` references, and these are made using the `fruit_data` table:

```
   fruit           fruit_data        data
----------------------------------------------
|  fruit_id    |   fruit_id     |    data_id |
|  ...         |   data_id      |    name    |
|  ...         |                |    ...     |
```

I'd like to select all `fruit.fruit_ids` that do not have a reference to a `data` row where `data.name` is "glass".

I've come up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fruit.fruit_id
FROM fruit
JOIN fruit_data ON fruit_data.fruit_id = fruit.fruit_id
JOIN data ON data.data_id = fruit_data.data_id
WHERE data.name != 'glass';
```

but this seems to exclude `fruit` rows that do not have any references to `data`.

So, how to write a query that returns all `fruit_ids` that either don't have *any* `data` rows or that only have `data` rows where `data.name != "glass"`?

Answer (score 0):

One method is `left join`s and `group by`:

```
SELECT f.fruit_id
FROM fruit f LEFT JOIN
     fruit_data fd
     ON fd.fruit_id = f.fruit_id LEFT JOIN
     data d
     ON d.data_id = fd.data_id 
GROUP BY f.fruit_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN d.name = 'glass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

But I think `not exists` is a more sensible method:

```
SELECT f.fruit_id
FROM fruit f 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM fruit_data fd
                       data d
                       ON d.data_id = fd.data_id 
                  WHERE fd.fruit_id = f.fruit_id AND
                        d.name = 'glass'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   fruit f
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   fruit_data fd
                   JOIN   data d ON fd.data_id = d.data.id
                   WHERE  fd.fruit_id = f.fruit_id AND
                          d.name = 'glass')
```